# FabricJs - How to reevaluate the points within an object after the object is rotated

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, coordinate-transformation

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {
  selection: false
});

var refRect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 250,
  top: 150,
  width: 200,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'transparent',
  stroke: 'blue',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});

canvas.add(refRect);

var refPoints = [
{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 200, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 100 },
  { x: 200, y: 100 }, { x: 30, y: 50 },
  { x: 50, y: 30 }

];

refPoints.map(function(point) {
  return new fabric.Circle({
    left: refRect.left - (refRect.width / 2) + point.x,
    top: refRect.top - (refRect.height / 2) + point.y,
    radius: 10,
    fill: 'blue',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
  });
}).forEach(function(refPoint) {
  canvas.add(refPoint);

});


var tarRect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 250, top: 150,
    width: 200, height: 100,
    fill: 'transparent',
    angle:45,
    stroke: 'red',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});

canvas.add(tarRect);

var matrix = tarRect.calcTransformMatrix();

refPoints.map(function(point) {
  return new fabric.Circle({
    left: tarRect.left - (tarRect.width / 2) + point.x,
    top: tarRect.top - (tarRect.height / 2) + point.y,
    radius: 5,
    fill: 'red',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
  });
}).forEach(function(refPoint) {
  canvas.add(refPoint);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fabric@1.7.11/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

I have a fabric rectangle object and a bunch of points relative to the rectangle. I was able to position the points within the rectangle using a simple logic

Now if i rotate the rectangle object by an angle, is there a way to evaluate the position of the points with respect to rotated rectangle.

I'm no expert in math, so i need some directions please assist.

Comment: Do you want that your points were attached to rectangle after rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use fabric group instead of your math logic.

```js
 const group = new fabric.Group([...points, rect]);

 canvas.add(group);
```

I prepared an example for more explanation about my solution, you can see it here
https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-bash-k01wv?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thanks Raman, however the grouping approach doesn't help me much since the points are dynamic. I was able to figure out an alternate approach using fabric.util.rotatePoint method. https://jsfiddle.net/spittingwiper/94ptqhok

Comment: Perhaps you should use the `getBoundingRect` method for calculating the position of your Rect? http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#getBoundingRect